# What are the parenthetical numbers in the combat HUD?

Tags: wizardry-8

During combat, the Wizardry 8 HUD displays numbers beside each enemy group's name, like so:

> 6 Soldier Ants ( 0 / 4 / 0)
>   3 Soldier Ants ( 2 / 1 / 1 )

What do the numbers in the parentheses mean?

[This thread](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/374906-wizardry-8/67355087) speculates they're "number total/number in target range/number visible," which sounds reasonable but doesn't match my experience in the game. The above example is taken directly from a fight, and obviously the first number isn't the total in the group (though often that first number *does* match the total). The middle number sometimes matches targets in range of my queued action, but doesn't seem to play nice with AoE effects so I don't think that's exactly the situation. The last number being the number visible on the screen is consistently born out in play, though.

The manual is strangely quiet on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can confirm that the enemy numbers in my version of the game match the format of yours, but they do not entirely match what is said around the internet, but through a quick bit of investigation here is what I have figured out:

1. The first value is the **number of active enemies** in the group. If you were facing a group of 5 enemies and all of them are active, this would be 5. However if two of them were asleep this value would only be 3. Apart from sleep and unconsciousness I have not yet determined what effects make an enemy inactive, although I think it is most likely that paralysis would as well.
2. The second value is the **number of enemies in range of the selected character**. If you select a melee character while at long range this would be 0, but selecting a ranged character would show some or all of the total members of the group.
3. The third value is the **number of visible enemies**, based on what you can currently see. If all enemies are in view, this will be the total, but if you turn the camera, or (you or an enemy) walk behind an obstruction, then this value will be less.

Comment: Thank you for the field work! Got any idea how the game determines a character's effective range? So far as I can tell, it's not counting queued spells.

Comment: I think it is based solely on currently equipped weapon.

Comment: I've done some experimentation of my own using this as a baseline, and it does seem to cue off weapon and *some* spells but not all. Also, Webbed and Paralysed definitely count as inactive.

Answer (score 0):

According to [SirTech's own FAQ](http://www.zimlab.com/wizardry/recovered/sir-tech/wizardry8/combat/combat101.html) they represent the monsters in range, monsters in view and the total number of the monsters in that group.